# Не работает X  и Gnome под FreeBSD

Tags: unix, freebsd, gnome

Запускаю графический интерфейс `gnome`, загружается нормально, но не работает мышь и клавиатура, то есть невозможно что-либо сделать. Система зависает и всё.
Как правильно настроить Иксы, `gnome`?

Answer (score 4):

Прописать в ee `/etc/rc.conf`

`hald_enable="YES"
dbus_enable="YES"`

И будет вам счастье.

Дополнение:

А сам `xorg` нормально создал свою конфигурацию? И еще вопрос, если вы ставили не из портов, то оно нормально и не ставится, в первом посту вам посоветовали собрать из портов, и это есть правильно. Единственное, что рекомендую делать это несколько иначе.

Если нету то ставим:

`% cd /usr/ports/sysutils/portupgrade
 % make install clean`

Потом делаем.

`$ portinstall -F gnome2`

Это нужно для того, чтобы система выкачала все сорцы. Процедура длинная, и если где-то там интернет упадет, то насыпет ошибок. Поэтому несколько раз (если с первого раза все зависимости не вытянет) запускаем эту команду. И только после этого запускаем.

`$portinstall gnome2`

Все это нужно лишь потому что `portinstall` делает зачистку мусора после сборки каждого порта автоматически. Если  стандартным `make`, то там после сборки соберется ооочень много добра, которое потом будете чистить. А мало ли и винта не хватит :). А с бинариков оно никогда нормально и не работало. FreeBSD - это всегда порты и сорцы, за что и уважаю эту систему, потому что это и есть концепция nix*, о которой некоторые позабыли (пальцем тыкать не стану).

Comment: Если б только это! Проблема несколько иная - не работает сам гномик, зависает при начальной загрузке, пробовал, переустанавливал и толку(

Comment: Может, это только у меня такая проблема, но хотелось бы избежать таких неприятностей...

Comment: Дополнил сообщение

Comment: Концепция юникс - это совсем не сырцы, а нечто иное.

Comment: И это нечто иное также.

Comment: Кстати, все системы, официально получившие право называться Unix, являются закрытыми и поставляются, есно, в бинарниках. А концепция юникса сама по себе - это в первую очередь набор утилит, принципы устройства программного интерфейса и организации файловой системы  и БОЛЬШЕ НИЧЕГО. Сырцы - это скорее в сторону GNU и т.д., что непосредственного отношения к юниксу как таковому не имеет.

Comment: Токо Вы не подумайте, что я юниксофоб. Совсем даже наоборот.

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /usr/ports/x11/gnome2
make config
make install clean
```

Answer (score 0):

Насколько помню, там надо пару строк в конфиге иксов поправить. В данный момент у меня под рукой фри с иксами нету, поэтому не могу написать сразу точно. Если вопрос до сих пор актуален, напишите, помогу разобраться. Мне нужны будут от Вас два файла - конфиг иксов и журнал запуска иксовой сессии.